# What is address of logical operation's result?

Tags: c#, assembly, jit

I have simple program written in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        a = a + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

I am newbie in such field of programming and my purpose is just to understand assembly code created by JIT. It is piece of asm code:

```
7:         int a = 0;
0000003c  xor         edx,edx 
0000003e  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx 
8:         for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
00000041  xor         edx,edx 
00000043  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],edx
```

I cannot understand code :`0000003c  xor         edx,edx`. Where is result of operation stored? I found only such quote from "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual":

> The logical instructions AND, OR, XOR (exclusive or), and NOT perform the standard Boolean operations for which 
>   they are named. The AND, OR, and XOR instructions require two operands; the NOT instruction operates on a 
>   single operand

EDIT: As I understand this result should be stored at `edx` (see next code line). But it seems weird for me. I thought that result will be pushed onto stack

Comment: It's stored in `edx`. This is equivalent to loading `edx` with zero, but is faster on intel architectures.

Comment: If you want to push things onto the stack you have to push them onto the stack using `push`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Logical operation instructions store results in the first argument - in your case, it's `edx`.

Note that XOR-ing a value with itself produces 0. Hence, `XOR a, a` is a common assembly idiom to clear a register.

Comment: Upvoted. Your important first sentence is missing from my answer.

Comment: It is useful information. It seems like I missed it from manual

Comment: I believe an `xor` is used because it is faster than a `mov`.

Comment: @slugster Yes, it is faster than `mov`, because it does not need extra cycles to read zero from code memory.

Answer (score 5):

`xor edx,edx` is the idiomatic way of clearing the `edx` register.

(Note that `a XOR a` is zero for any value of `a`.)